# How to include model in my razor view in DD4T

Tags: 2011, dd4t

I am trying to add reference of my model in the _layout or component view but for latter it's saying two models are not allowed since there is already -

```
@model IComponent
```

And when I try to add a model(`@model Test.Navigation`) on top of my _layout view the error is -

```
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyWebSite.ViewModels.Navigation]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DD4T.ContentModel.IPage'."
```

Please confirm if models other than the IComponent or IPage are allowed? If so, how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use any class as a model in DD4T. Generally in MVC Layout files don't usually have a model. If I was you I would create an Action method called Render in a controller called NavigationController and then call that using [`Html.Action()`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/) in your Layout file.

Your View for this Action can then be the model you want and your logic for rendering the navigation information can be encapsulated in a single method.

Comment: How can I pass model in Action, it only allows the following as paramenter- this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues

Comment: You should retreive the information for your model and create an instance of your model in the action method rather than trying to pass the model from the view to the action. Think about Model View Controller principles.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know DD4T supports IComponent/IPage as models for the view.

But you can use ViewData or ViewBag (works only for MVC 4 since it's dependent on C# 4.0) classes to pass additional information to the View.

ViewData is a dictionary of key/value pairs and ViewBag uses C# 4.0 features to have dynamic properties that can be accessed in the view.

Read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem).

Hope this helps resolve your query.

Comment: Using VD or Vbag means passing values from Controller to view which will omit the M of MVC, is it not possible to also include Model in _layout as it doesn't require @model IComponent/IPage ?

Comment: You can use any class as a model in DD4T See: http://kahwah.me/2013/3/viewmodels-in-dd4t http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/dd4t-marking-up-your-view-models/ and http://albertromkes.com/2013/03/18/domain-drive-development-with-dd4t-and-xpm/